# iPhone/Mobile app and mobile-site

Tags: feature-request, iphone, optimization

Are there any news about an official iPhone app or a Mobile optimized website for SO?

I love SO and I'd like to check my question status and to manage my personal informations. Is there someone working on it? I get it's pretty hard to do, but, seriously, this is a programming website and no one is programming an app for it? I found Six to Eight which is great, but it has no account manager settings.

Meanwhile could you please create a mobile optimized version, so that logging, writing and reading get a little bit easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [StackExchange Api V1.0](https://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help) is **read only** and that's the main reason why no one is programming an app for it.<sup>*</sup>

Quoting Jeff [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/stack-exchange-api-public-beta-starts/):

> Version 1 is read only. Coming up with
> a solid API is hard enough without
> adding writing and authentication to
> the mix. For the initial release, it’s
> a read-only API. We’ll take on the
> much more challenging problem of
> writing (and authentication) in v2.

If you are looking for an optimized mobile site for your reading pleasure, have a look to [StackMobile](http://www.stackmobile.com).

<sup>*I believe there won't be any V2.0 version with write support in the near future</sup>

Comment: What about a mobile-optimized-website?

Answer (score 2):

The (beta) mobile theme has been rolled out to all sites on Stack Exchange, you should be able to see it on your mobile devices.

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98215/stack-exchange-mobile-theme-beta-starts-now).

Answer (score 1):

Just as standardization and as a suggestion, from someone that worked with mobile sites for the past 2 years, keep the subdomain m.stackoverflow.com as your mobile version as well of the site and if possible, when detecting the mobile phone (can be done using WURFL), do a redirect to either one automatically. It is quite painful to create this logic with 100% of achievement but it is worth it for the mobile experience.